# is it possible to reconnect subprocess.Popen's stdout to sys.stdout? (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a python program that runs another program using popen.  Is it possible to read from the programme's output for a while, and the connect the subprogram's output to `sys.stdout`, and allow it to run in parallel as if I had started it without the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` option?

wrapper:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
from time import sleep
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(
  ["./count.py"],
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,''):
  l = line.decode('utf-8')
  sys.stdout.write(">>" + l)
  if "8" in l:
    # somehow reconnect p.stdout to sys.stdout
    break

sleep(1)

print("now do some stuff in parallel")

sleep(1)

p.terminate()
```

test program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep
import sys

for x in range(1,100):
  sleep(.1)
  print x
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

output:

```
$ ./wrapper.py
>>1
>>2
>>3
>>4
>>5
>>6
>>7
>>8
now do some stuff in parallel
```

is it possible to do this?

```
$ ./wrapper.py
>>1
>>2
...
>>7
>>8
9
10
...
18
19
now do some stuff in parallel
20
21
...
28
29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "reconnect" the file descriptors of a subprocess you've already launched (except perhaps with very dirty and OS-specific tricks). The only file descriptor you have control over, is the one that's still in your process, and it's only useful for reading. So if you want things to go to stdout, then everything that comes into the read end would have to be copied to stdout somehow.

Fortunately, you can always spawn another subprocess to do that. This is just the kind of thing that the handy Unix utility `cat` does well.

```
subprocess.Popen(
  ["/bin/cat"],
  stdin=p.stdout,
)
```

This will basically create a pipeline, where you pipe the output of one process into another process. It can be very useful. In this case the other process (`cat`) just outputs to stdout.

Comment: that's great.  works as long as I have the sleep in the test program.  When I remove the sleep I get something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Ghn.png (a big gap between the last line processed by the loop and the first line that got pipe into cat.  any ideas?

Comment: hmmm... maybe try doing an explicit p.stdout.close() after creating the pipeline (so that your copy is closed and Python can't mess with it. The subprocesses will still have their copies).